# Foreach with %dopar% is not able to detect user defined function inside a user defined function

Tags: r, function, loops, foreach

I am running a foreach loop with %dopar% in R. I have created two user defined function. I call one user defined function, say X inside another user-defined function, say Y. foreach is unable to detect the function X, if I create list, L containing Function Y and call function Y from L.

I have tried using .export. My function can run smoothly if I do not use list of functions with function Y containing function X.

The minimal working code is as follows:

```
# Define the function
Fun1=function(x){
  a=2*x
  b=3*x
  c=a+b
  return(c)
}
Fun2=function(x){
  a=x
  b=Fun1(x)
  c=a+b
  return(c)
}

# Create a list containing function Fun1 and Fun2
Funlist=list(Fun1, Fun2)

# Create a variable
x=1

# Run Normal Loop
for(i in 1:10){
  a=Funlist[[1]](x)
}
### Output: a=6

# Run the foreach loop
library("foreach")
library("parallel")
library("doParallel")
library("DoE.base")

registerDoParallel(7)

## Scenario 1: Run foreach loop with Fun2
df_c=foreach(seed = 1:10, .combine=rbind)%dopar%{a=Fun2(x)}
### Output: No error

## Scenario 2: Run foreach loop with Fun1 from Funlist
df_c=foreach(seed = 1:10, .combine=rbind)%dopar%{a=Funlist[[1]](x)}
### Output: No error

## Scenario 3: Run foreach loop with Fun2 from Funlist
df_c=foreach(seed = 1:10, .combine=rbind)%dopar%{a=Funlist[[2]](x)}
### Output: Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "Fun1""
```

I expect the output to be no error with df_c giving me the dataframe.

Comment: In your last code, `foreach` is clever enough to see that it needs to export `Fun2`, but not that it needs also `Fun1` inside `Fun2` so that you need to export it yourself.

Comment: Is `Funlist=c("Fun1", "Fun2")` supposed to be `Funlist=list(Fun1, Fun2)`? Because otherwise I can't get your non-parallel code to run either. I'm not sure if you are trying to store the names of the functions or the functions themselves.

Comment: @ MrFlick Yes I agree. I was trying to create the list of functions. So, ```Funlist=list(Fun1, Fun2)``` is what I used. Thanks for pointing out. I have edited my comment.

Comment: @F.Privé Ok. Can you suggest how to export the function because ```.export=c("Fun1")``` did not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Reprex

```
# Define the functions
Fun1 <- function(x) 2 * x
Fun2 <- function(x) Fun1(x + 1)

# Create a list containing functions Fun1 and Fun2
Funlist <- list(Fun1, Fun2)

# Run the foreach loop
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cl <- makeCluster(2))

## Scenario 1: Run foreach loop with Fun2 
## Output: No error
foreach(x = 1:10) %dopar% Fun2(x)

## Scenario 2: Run foreach loop with Fun1 from Funlist 
## Output: No error
foreach(x = 1:10) %dopar% Funlist[[1]](x)

## Scenario 3: Run foreach loop with Fun2 from Funlist
## Output: Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "Fun1""
foreach(x = 1:10) %dopar% Funlist[[2]](x)
```

#### Solution

My preferred solution: never rely on global objects and always pass objects as arguments of the functions.

```
Fun3 <- function(x, Fun) Fun(x + 1)
Funlist2 <- list(Fun1, Fun3)
foreach(x = 1:10) %dopar% Funlist2[[2]](x, Funlist2[[1]])

stopCluster(cl)
```